# Perf4j @profiled annotation for private method

Tags: java, spring, perf4j

I have added `@Profiled` annotation for public and private method. I can see the timing logs for public methods. But there is no timing logs for private methods.

I did the configurations correctly.

```
@Profiled
public BigInteger nextPrime() {
    currentPrime = currentPrime.nextProbablePrime();
    return currentPrime;
}

@Profiled
private void test()
{
    try{
    Thread.sleep(100);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

**Is @profiled annotation only applicable for only public methods?**

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have configured perf4j with Spring AOP and since Spring AOP proxies are not invoked when a method is called from inside the same class (as in your case with the `test` method), no performance statistics will be recorded.

Check out [this](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2011/10/spring-pitfalls-proxying.html) blog post which explains Spring AOP pitfalls

One solution to your problem would be to use AspectJ with perf4j, since AspectJ can handle this type of situation

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is limitation of the Spring AOP:

> When using proxies, you should apply the you annotations only to
>   methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected, private
>   or package-visible methods with these annotations, no error is raised,
>   but the annotated method does not exhibit the configured caching
>   settings. Consider the use of AspectJ (see below) if you need to
>   annotate non-public methods as it changes the bytecode itself.”